# React Native: Sharing state, api call responses between contexts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

What is the proper structure arrangement when sharing the result of an call in one context to another?

Suppose I have two concerns: one deals with everything QR code related (camera permissions, scanning, etc) and the other deals with everything student related (lists, api calls, etc)

QrContext:

```
import React from 'react';
import createDataContext from './createDataContext';

const qrReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'start':
            return {...state, cameraOpen: true, code: null, scanned: false };
        case 'end': {
            return {...state, cameraOpen: false, code: null };
        }
        case 'scan': {
            return {...state, code: action.payload, scanned: true };
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
const startCamera = dispatch => () => {
  dispatch({ type: 'start' });
};

const stopCamera = dispatch => () => {
  dispatch({ type: 'end' });
};

const scan = dispatch => ( data ) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'scan', payload: data });
};

export const { Provider, Context } = createDataContext(
    qrReducer,
    { startCamera, stopCamera, scan },
    { cameraOpen: false, code: null, scanned: false }
);
```

StudentsContext:

```
import createDataContext from './createDataContext';

const studentsReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'student':
            return {...state, students: [...state.students, action.payload]};
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const findStudentQR = dispatch => async (qr) => {
    const res = await API.get('/student', {
        params: {
            id: qr
        }
    });
    if(res.data && res.data._id) {
//...
    } else {
//...
    }
    dispatch({ type: 'student', payload: res.data});

};

export const { Provider, Context } = createDataContext(
    studentsReducer,
    { findStudentQR },
    { students: [] }
);
```

And then to share the state between them, a hook:
useStudentQR:

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { Context as QrContext } from '../context/QrContext';
import { Context as StudentsContext } from '../context/StudentsContext';
import { navigate } from "../navigationRef";

export default () => {
    const { state: { code }, stopCamera } = useContext(QrContext);
    const { state: {students}, findStudentQR } = useContext(StudentsContext);
    const readStudent =  async () => {
        const student =  await findStudentQR(code);
        stopCamera();
        navigate('Student');
    };
    return [readStudent];
}
```

And then my ScanScreen:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, Button } from 'react-native';
import { BarCodeScanner } from 'expo-barcode-scanner';
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';
import { Context as QrContext } from '../context/QrContext';
import useQR from '../hooks/useQR';
import useStudentQR from '../hooks/useStudentQR';

const ScanScreen = () => {
    const { state: { scanned }, startCamera, stopCamera, scan } = useContext(QrContext);
    const [err] = useQR(true); // asks for camera permission
    const [readStudent] = useStudentQR();

    return <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ top: "always" }} style={styles.view}>
        <NavigationEvents onWillFocus={startCamera} />
        <BarCodeScanner
            onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : readStudent}
            style={styles.camera}
        />
    </SafeAreaView>
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    ...
});

export default ScanScreen
```

So my current problem is that inside of `useStudentQr`, it doesn't have the updated result of the scan function.

I believe this is because when I call `useStudentQr` inside of `ScanScreen`, the state at the time has `code` set to null. When I call `readStudent()`, it is still using the old instance of the `useStudentQr`.

What is the proper way to handle logic between contexts? Is it meant to be done within the form?